# Debugging issue in testng test cases

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

I am using intelliJ v2021.3.2 (Community Edition)

My project is a java Maven TestNG (v7.4.0) project

When I run test cases it executes successfully, but when I try to debug I get the following error :

Intellij displays error "Test Framework quit unexpectedly"

and this is the error in console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/lang/WeakPairMap$Pair$Weak
    ..
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:107)
```

The following is a code example (I'm using SHAFT engine) but any test case anyway debugging is not working with all

```
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void UserCanLogin() {

            homeObject = new HomePage(driver);
            profilePageObject = new ProfilePage(driver);
            loginObject = new LoginPage(driver);

            homeObject.openLoginPage();
            loginObject.UserLogin(individualUserMail, individualUserPassword);

            Validations.assertThat().element(driver, profilePageObject.getProfileIconDropDown()).exists().perform();
            profilePageObject.ProfileIconDropDown();
            profilePageObject.userLogOut();

    }
```

Comment: Post your code, we can't see what what is on your screen.

Comment: @TalAngel Done. but it's not working with any testng test case even if the test case contains system.out.println("hello"); only the debugging still doesn't work

Comment: Hello. Please file an issue at the YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the code sample provided. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Disabling "Instrumenting agent" worked for me. To do that you need to disable the async stack traces agent in "**Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Async Stack Traces**"

Comment: Not worked on MacOS Monterey 12.6 with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition) Build #IC-223.8214.52, built on December 20, 2022 Runtime version: 17.0.5+1-b653.23 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassCircularityError` is thrown when some class is a (indirect) superclass of itself, some interface (indirectly) extends itself or similar.

So, check if you declared homeObject to be HomePage or other wrong class by mistake. Take a 2nd look at your code and figure out where there is circularity.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. but the same code runs fine and debug is working on my other colleague machine. This is why I'm not sure if it's a code issue

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Java version in the "Edit configuration" from Java 17 to Java 8 worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).